# My data table not fix to page How can I show my table in whole page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have datatable but it shows in half of the page. I want to show in the whole page.

Following is the image of table shows in half-page 
[image]

```
<style>
  .table {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/custom/css/custom_style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel=" https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap4.min.css">

<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
       <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="overflow-x: auto;">
          <thead class="bg-info">
          <tr>
            <th>E.Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
             <th>Update</th>
            <th>Disable</th>
            <th>Upload</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table-hover">
            <?php foreach($employees as $post){?>
          <tr>
          <td><?php echo $post->user_id;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $user_full_name;?></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Update</i></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash">  Update</i></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash">  Update</i></td>
         </tr>
          <?php }?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var table     = $('#example1').DataTable( {
  scrollY:        "500px",
  scrollX:        true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging:         false,
  fixedColumns:   true
 });
});
</script>
```

In the table, I add overflow-x auto  `style="overflow-x: auto;"` but it not working.
I do not know how what is missing in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below style

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
```